# How to insert a string with double quotes in the first line of my csv file?

Tags: php, sed

I am looking for a way to insert this:

```
"random1","random2"
```

in the first line of my csv file using sed.
Tried hard and only got this:

```
sed -i -e '1irandom1 random2\' filename
```

Output is just random1 and random2 without any double quotes - clearly.
Any good idea?

Comment: can you tag this better, what language etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
sed -i -e '1i"random","random2"\' filename
```

If you want the quotes (and the comma), you need to explicitly specify what is written, verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

If you want double quotes, type double quotes:

```
sed -i~ -e '1s/^/"random1","random2"/' filename
```

`i` inserts a line, so I used substitution `s`, replacing `^`, i.e. the beginning of the line, by the given string.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me. actually my problem was due to a mistake in my php-syntax. therefore there was any kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

`sed 's/^.*$/"random1","random2"/g' filename` would  work.